# Xcode 4 - viewDidLoad issue

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, ipad

Is anyone else having issues with Xcode 4 where `viewDidLoad` is being called twice? I have run the same project in both Xcode 3.2 and Xcode 4 and it only acts up in Xcode 4.

Comment: Is your viewDidLoad being called twice only for a particular UIViewController or for all of your view controllers?  Also, how do you know it is called twice on the same viewController (breakpoints, nslog)?  To be sure it is the same UIViewController, can you do NSLog(@"called twice %p", self) in the viewDidLoad.  The %p will display the hex address of the object.

Comment: Break points and nslog statements. It only happens in xcode 4, i downloaded 3.2.6 last night and the project runs fine in there. Its only my rootviewcontroller when the application first launchs. After I  finish testing and push it to the app store I will try xcode 4 again and the log statement you mentioned. I really thinks its xcode 4, its a universal app with seperate nibs and on launch they are loading completely different code yet it happens in both and theres nothing new in my ipad app which has been throughly tested and approved by apple.

Comment: I'd be interested to know what happens from those NSLogs when you tackle the problem again.  Good luck with everything.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. @Caleb, remember that there's a big compiler change from Xcode 3 to Xcode 4. Xcode is not "just an IDE", includes a lot of other things. The instance of the view controller is always the same, it's not a multiple viewcontroller issue: view did load <FaceViewController_iPhone: 0x1d52a3d0>
view did load <FaceViewController_iPhone: 0x1d52a3d0>

Comment: Yeah as of now I have switched to 3.2.6 and have had no problems running my code and submitting to the app store. I'm going to wait until the next build of xcode 4 to switch.

Comment: An update: This appears to have been fixed in iOS 5.

Comment: As Renegade said, I tried to check the object using the NSLog(@"called twice %p", self), On testing this "viewDidLoad" is getting called only once. I am frustrated in what situation it happened, But Now it is ok.

Answer (score 4):

After researching this on the [Apple Developer forums](https://devforums.apple.com/message/407848), it seems that in some cases Xcode 4 creates bugged Interface Builder NIBs. The effect is that the application's rootViewController gets loaded in twice, which really screws things up. The same project loaded in Xcode 3 won't exhibit the problem.

In my universal app, it only affected the iPad NIB. The iPhone was fine.

I was able to solve this issue by:

- Removing the rootViewController connection in Interface Builder (this causes the app to load with `window.rootViewController = nil`)
- In viewDidLoad for the main controller (the one that was being loaded twice), I then manually assign `appDelegate.window.rootViewController = self`

So far this seems to have the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode is just the IDE -- it shouldn't have any bearing on what happens when your app is executing. If there's a difference, it seems more likely that you're building for different iOS versions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know xcode is just an ide.. i'm target 4.2 and building with 4.3 sdk in both xcode 4 and 3.2.6 and i only have trouble with xcode 4. And even if I was building for different versions my viewdidload shouldnt be called twice before my app didfinishlaunching with no memory warnings or anything.

Comment: I recommend filing a bug report at bugreporter.apple.com.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the view of the view controller? I had the same issue and I realized that I didn't set the view property.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    UIView *contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
    //add some stuff to contentView here
    self.view = contentView;
    [contentView release];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. And i resolved it. It happens when your app memory did get memory warning.

Put a breakpoint to memoryDidReceiveWarning. It get's called, and clear your class object memory. So your viewDidLoad Get called twice, because it has no memory at that time.